# Create a list from Array React JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Im trying to create an array to store my category links and then display them however I'm getting nothing displaying in my DOM. Any help would be appreciated :)

```
import React from "react";
import { SidebarCategory } from './SidebarCategory';

class SidebarCategories extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            categories: []
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({categories: [
            {
                id: 1,
                icon: "icon",
                title: "Home",
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                icon: "icon",
                title: "Gallery",
            }
        ]});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul className="sidebar__categories container-fluid">
                {this.state.categories.map(category => {
                    return (
                        <SidebarCategory key={category.id} title={category.title} />
                    )
                })};
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

export default SidebarCategories;
```

edit:

console error:

bundle.js:357 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `Sidebar`.
    in Sidebar (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App

sidebarCategory.js

```
import React from "react";

export class SidebarCategory extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const SidebarCategory = ({ title }) => {
          return (<div className="sidebarCategory">{title}</div>);
        }
    }
}
```

sidebar.js:

```
import React from "react";

import { SidebarCategories } from "./SidebarCategories";

export class Sidebar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="sidebar col-sm-2">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="sidebar__header col">
                        <img alt="Logo" className="img-fluid sidebar__header__logo" src="../resources/img/logo-white.png" />
                        {'\u00A0'} <h4 className="i-block">Title</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="sidebar__user container-fluid">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-sm-4">
                                <img alt="User DP" className="sidebar__user__img img-fluid rounded-circle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-sm-8">
                                <p><strong>Welcome</strong><br />
                                Mark Hughes</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <SidebarCategories />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import Sidebar from "./components/sidebar";
import Content from "./components/content";

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <Sidebar />
                <Content />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

render(<App className="container-fluid"/>, window.document.getElementById("app"));
```

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: bundle.js:357 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `Sidebar`.
    in Sidebar (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App

Comment: @MarkHughes88 where you are using loop to create the elements, also can you show `SidebarCategory` component?

Comment: ah. I dont think i have looped through them. wheres best to do that?

Comment: Do you have any files named "Sidebar.js"? Looks like you have not exported anything from that file. The error is related to that file.

Comment: yes i have a sidebar.js, ive added it to the original post

Comment: remove `{}` from this: `import { SidebarCategories } from "./SidebarCategories";`. Should be `import  SidebarCategories  from "./SidebarCategories";` As for the looping, just follow what Andy said below.

Comment: Well spotted, @WinChiu.

Comment: well ive done that. now im getting another error. Looks like its something to do in my index.js file. the error: bundle.js:357 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `App`.

Comment: Follow @Andrew 's advice below for that error. I notice you use both `export` and `export default`.

Comment: Im giving it a go, having some trouble though. And im not sure what the difference is to be honest. Ive just been trying out both while testing this

Comment: When you use `export`, you can export multiple classes (and functions, const, variables) from one file. That's why you need to write it as `import {what_should_be_imported} from ...` ( the `{}` is needed to specify what you want to import). While `export default` can only export one "thing" from a file (a class or a variable or a const). That's why you can write it as `import [the_name_of_imported] from ...` (no `{}` is needed). What error do you get now?

Comment: ah ok. well ive updated my first post with the current files. the error im getting is: bundle.js:357 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `App`.
    in App

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import React from "react";
import SidebarCategory from './SidebarCategory';

class SidebarCategories extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            categories: []
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({categories: [
            {
                id: 1,
                title: "Home",
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                title: "Gallery",
            }
        ]});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul className="sidebar__categories container-fluid">
                <SidebarCategory categories={this.state.categories} />
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

export default SidebarCategories;
```

And add this in your SidebarCategory file:-

```
import React from "react";

export class SidebarCategory extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <li className="sidebar__category container-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                      <div className="col-sm-10">
                          {this.props.categories.map((category, key) =>(
                            <span key={key}>{category.title}</span>
                          ))}
                      </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. this fixed my issue after id sorted out the {} with my imports. One more question. Each of these categories have pages, and im trying to map those into each instance of the SidebarCategory. Am I right in thinking id just use that syntax and nest it?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you're not iterating over your categories you have held in state, so the first thing is to `map` over them and provide your sub-component `<SidebarCategory>` the data it needs; a key from the category id, and the title.

```
render() {
  return (
    <ul className = "sidebar__categories container-fluid">
    {this.state.categories.map(category => {
      return (
        <SidebarCategory
          key={category.title}
          title={category.title}
        />
      )
    })}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Then your `<SidebarCategory>` component should return a `div` (for example) the title of which is filled in from the `props` that you've provided it.

```
const SidebarCategory = ({ title }) => {
  return <div className="SidebarCategory">{title}</div>
}

export default SidebarCategory;
```

Comment: so am i right in thinking that i mapping through them in the sidebarCategories render function, and in my SidebarCategory component im rendering a const? As that's what I've done and im still getting the console error and nothing on my DOM

Comment: ye, now I'm getting this error: bundle.js:304 Uncaught Error: SidebarCategory.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

Comment: wrap the return value with (). Should be `return (<div className="SidebarCategory">{title}</div>);`

Comment: @WinChiu, the braces are only necessary if the JSX is on the next line, or if it's split over several lines.

Comment: @Andy, ah.. just realized that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First in SidebarCategories

```
import {SidebarCategory}... //with curly braces
```

Second in Sidebar:

```
import SidebarCategories from "./SidebarCategories"; //without curly braces
```

See:

```
export class SidebarCategory //no default -> import {SidebarCategory} from...
export default SidebarCategories; //with default -> import SidebarCategories from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these:
index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import Sidebar from "./components/sidebar";
import Content from "./components/content";

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <Sidebar />
                <Content />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

render(<App className="container-fluid"/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Sidebar.js

```
import React from "react";

import SidebarCategories from "./SidebarCategories";

class Sidebar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="sidebar col-sm-2">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="sidebar__header col">
                        <img alt="Logo" className="img-fluid sidebar__header__logo" src="../resources/img/logo-white.png" />
                        {'\u00A0'} <h4 className="i-block">Title</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="sidebar__user container-fluid">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-sm-4">
                                <img alt="User DP" className="sidebar__user__img img-fluid rounded-circle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-sm-8">
                                <p><strong>Welcome</strong><br />
                                Mark Hughes</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <SidebarCategories />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Sidebar;
```

SidebarCategory.js

```
import React from "react";

class SidebarCategory extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <div className="row">
                      <div className="col-sm-10">
                          {this.props.category.title}
                      </div>
                </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SidebarCategory;
```

SidebarCategories.js

```
import React from "react";
import SidebarCategory from './SidebarCategory';

class SidebarCategories extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            categories: []
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({categories: [
            {
                id: 1,
                title: "Home",
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                title: "Gallery",
            }
        ]});
    }

    render() {
        let list = this.state.categories.map((category) => {
          <li className="sidebar__category container-fluid" key={category.id}><SidebarCategory category={category} /></li>
        });

        return (
            <ul className="sidebar__categories container-fluid">
                {list}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

export default SidebarCategories;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is in your sidebarCategory.js, you created a stateless (arrow function) component inside a stateful component.

since its just a component that render data from its props you can use the stateless/arrow function alone like this.

```
    const SidebarCategory = ({ title }) => {
      return (<div className="sidebarCategory">{title}</div>);
    }
    export default SidebarCategory; // this way its exported as default component, import it without using curly brackets (import SidebarCategory from './SidebarCategory';
    // OR
    export SidebarCategory; // this way its exported as non-default component, import it using the curly brackets (import {SidebarCategory} from './SidebarCategory';
```